# implementing bubble sort using foldr haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement bubble sort using foldr but I keep getting error messages saying types not matching and I'm not understanding why.
Here's my code:

```
bubble :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
bubble [x] = [x]
bubble (x:y:xs)
   | x > y = y : x:xs
   | otherwise = x : bubble (y:xs)

bubbleSorting :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
bubbleSorting = foldr bubble []
```

Comment: Well, `foldr` takes a two-argument function, and `bubble` is only a one-argument function.

Comment: okay, I don't understand how I could change bubble to be a two-argument function

Comment: You should post the error messages and what specifically you don't understand about them. Also open ghci and do `:t foldr` and think carefully about what the arguments all do and hoe they line up with the ones you've supplied

Comment: @Sophie For what it's worth, I think the reaction "how can I change `bubble`" is a dangerous one, because it is too narrow. You definitely need to change some part of the code, but just looking at two pieces that don't fit together and arbitrarily choosing one to cram into the hole left by the other one seems unwise. I encourage you to try to write `bubbleSorting` with manual recursion first, and then try to spot any recursive patterns only afterwards.

Comment: for any `f1 x` you can always define `f2 x y = f1 x`, or `f2 x y = f1 y`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `bubble` function approximately inserts `x` into the sorted list `y:xs`. If we change the first pattern match from `[x]` to the equivalent `(x:[])` you can see that `bubble` always takes a value `x` and a remainder of the list (the list it's being inserted into), either `[]` or `y:xs`.

```
bubble :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
bubble (x:[]) = [x]
bubble (x:y:xs)
   | x > y = y : x:xs
   | otherwise = x : bubble (y:xs)
```

This can be converted into a function that takes two arguments by removing the `:` constructor between `x` and the list it's being inserted into.

```
bubble :: (Ord a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
bubble x [] = [x]
bubble x (y:xs)
   | x > y = y : x:xs
   | otherwise = x : bubble y xs
```

This is nice; it makes `bubble` a total function. It's no longer undefined on `[]` and is compatible with `foldr`.

There's still a logic error in `bubble`. I suggest you try `bubbleSorting [10,9..1]`. You might be surprised by the result.

---

If you don't want to change the signature of `bubble` you can instead define `bubble' x ys = bubble (x:ys)` and use `bubble'` in `foldr`.

Comment: There is a logic error, but not only in `bubble` (assuming we want to actually perform a bubblesort): bubble-sort doesn't have the shape of a `foldr`, but of an `iterate` or similar.

Comment: @Daniel Wagner I believe `bubbleSort` should take "at most" length many repetitions of an internal recursive function (`bubble` here) and if implemented by `foldr` might even turn out to be more efficient since it won't need to make a recursive call if `x < y` anymore as the rest would already be sorted.

Comment: The sort described in this post is an insertion sort. If your algorithm doesn't consist of many passes of swapping adjacent inversions, it's not a bubble sort.

Comment: @Carl It's only insertion sort because it's built up incrementally from `foldr`. As long as `bubble` is unnecessarily in the `otherwise` branch it keeps swapping adjacent inversions (there aren't any) past the item bubbling up from the beginning of the list. This consists of many passes of swapping adjacent inversions and _still isn't bubble sort_. The difference between insertion sort and bubble sort is which items are included in each pass. Insertion sort excludes the first items from the early passes; bubble sort excludes the last items from the late passes.

Comment: @Carl Insertion sort can terminate early on each pass, improving its best case running time. Bubble sort can terminate early on the number of passes performed.

Comment: @DanielWagner exactly. though `iterate f x !! n = foldr g x [1..n]` with some `g`.

Comment: @Cirdec Given if I changed the signature it would be an insertion sort, I defined `bubble'` and I have now got a working programme - thanks

Comment: @WillNess Sure. But, e.g., `dropWhile (uncurry (/=)) . ap zip tail . iterate f` doesn't seem like it has a corresponding `foldr` form.

Comment: @DanielWagner not very "natural" one, but it can be "faked" with `ap zip tail $ let {g i r x | x/= y = r y | otherwise = repeat x where y = f x} in foldr g undefined [1..] x`. a natural would be an unfold, `unfoldr (\x -> [(x,y) | let y=f x, y/=x])` (with MonadComprehensions for brevity); though there might be an off-by-one error there.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may implement the `bubbleSort` function with `foldr` as follows;

```
bubbleSort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
bubbleSort xs = foldr bubble [] xs
                where
                bubble x []     = [x]
                bubble x (y:ys) | x < y     = x:y:ys
                                | otherwise = y:bubble x ys
```

Comment: the bubble in bubble sort goes all the way through. your `bubble` performs an insertion into what it assumes to be a sorted list.